# Change (Arabic) language within the application

Tags: ios, localization, autolayout, arabic, ios-autolayout

I am creating an application where i have used english and arabic language. I have created this application with autolayout. The tricky part i am facing is that user can change the language settings from the application as well.

Autolayout is working fine if i change the language from the device settings app.But when i change the language from my application, I have to re-start the app to localize the content as well as it does not localize the xib's. Is there any way to achieve this for localizing xib using autolayout to change it for hebrew (Right to Left) language without creating different xibs. I want my xib's get localize for arabic text as well, If i change the language from the settings app. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to implement a language chooser within your application? You should just use the language that the user has chosen in Settings to prevent confusion.

Comment: Hi @wakachamo, I know that it must be implement as like you suggested, But client has such requirements. I just want to know is there any way to localize the xib when user changes language from within the application for Right to Left languages.

Comment: There is no easy way, and you will run into issues where system UI called from your app will still be in the system language. In addition, other localisable components like date and number formatters will also not obey manually specified languages. I would highly recommend you ask your client to reconsider this requirement.